# How to join with DB::table and orderBy jointable attribute set 0 if no join found

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a DB::table query that I make a join with. In case the join is not possible, I want to set the value of the attribute that I'm looking for with my join to 0 for the order. With my current query, entries that have no join are ignored.

```
$d_list = DB::table('d')->where('active', 1)
    ->join('d_scores', 'd_id', '=', 'd.id')
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('(case when d_scores.totalscore is null then 0 else d_scores.totalscore end)'), 'desc')
    ->orderBy('u_24h', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('d.nf', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('d.id', 'desc')
    ->get(array('d.id', 'd_scores.totalscore'));

foreach($d_list as $key => $d){
    if($d->id == $data['d']->id){
        $d_rank = $key+1;
        break;
    }
}
```

I have a table with 1000 entries. Out of these 1000, only 100 have a row in the join table. I want to order the result of 1000 based on the value of the attribute that only 100 have though. The 900 other entries that don't have a row in the join table need to get the value 0 for that specific attribute that doesn't exist for them (d_scores.totalscore). But because the join doesn't exist for them, these entries are not taken anymore at all.

Comment: Not sure why the need to write SQL like that, write it pure and escape the variables.  
It is way more portable and maintainable that way. Besides, what u ask does not make any sense (to me... I might be misunderstanding). You have 2 tables you want joined. Some records will have a match, some not. Did I get it right?

Comment: I have a table with 1000 entries. Out of these 1000, only 100 have a row in the join table. I want to order the result of the 1000 based on the value of the attribute that only 100 have though. The 900 other entries that don't have a row in the join table need to get the value 0 for that specific attribute that doesn't exist for them (d_scores.totalscore). But because the join doesn't exists for them, these entries are not taken anymore at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.id,IFNULL(B.field_that_might_be_matched,0)
FROM table_a A
LEFT JOIN
     table_b B
ON
     A.id = B.table_a_id
ORDER BY 2
```

The **LEFT JOIN** will make sure the result will show all entries in table A, regardless if they have a match in table B. If there is no match in table B, it means there is no value for **B.field_that_might_be_matched** in the result. By default, MySQL will put there NULL.

The **ISNULL** condition will turn it from **NULL** to **0**. **ORDER BY 2**, order it by the second field in the select list (Check this here, it's been some time since I used this syntax).

Sadly, I do not support this pseudo MySQL in PHP, which seems smart, but actually, isn't.  So the example is in pure SQL. I think it is easy to translate to the "ORM" you use.

Comment: Thanks, changing the join to a left join did it already. No need to check for IFNull anymore as well.!